# Command to find a file in a directory in widows

Tags: windows, command-line

I like to find a file **xyz.properties** in my project. I like to know which command is useful for this. The same file name is exisiting in multiple folders in the project directory.

Answer (score 2):

Either use the windows search function, or from a command prompt use this command:

`dir xyz.properties /s /b`

If you have a lot of occurences, you can save the result to a textfile by appending `> file.txt`

This way you can open file.txt and read all results.

you can use wildcard `*` as part or whole of the name.

For example: `dir *.prop* /s /b` will find all occurrences of any filename with extension starting with prop.